# RadEditor not Showing in RadGrid Edit Form Popup

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid

I created a rad grid and it's popup edit form is also working fine. But when i replace a multiline text box with RadEditor it gives following error

> Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Could not find a
>   part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS
>   Express\~\EmployeeInfo\css\BasicTools.xml'.

and popup form is not displayed. Anyone please suggest the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you attempting to implement the RadEditor in a popup as given in Telerik's demo [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/editorastextbox/defaultcs.aspx)?  If so, note that the RadEditor in their demo is loading its tools list from a BasicTools.xml file, like so:

```
<telerik:RadEditor Height="150px" Width="300px" ToolsWidth="330px" EditModes="Design"
                               ID="RadEditor1" runat="server" ToolbarMode="ShowOnFocus" ToolsFile="~/Editor/Examples/EditorAsTextBox/BasicTools.xml">
```

The error you're seeing indicates your RadEditor is looking for BasicTools.xml and not finding it in the specified location.  Either correct your path in the ToolsFile attribute, or move the file to the proper place.